# HTML5 Canvas not rendering automatically

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, ionic-framework

I am building a html5 js ionic mobile app. and short story is I cannot get my canvas to initialize the first image in a sequence on each view load. So each view is a task and each task has a set of images that I cycle through on click... My problem is that I'm trying to show the 1st image in each set before any clicks happen. So a case would be: a user chooses a task, navigates to that view and is presented with a canvas (blank at the moment, well sometimes this behavior miraculous works).

Each time the controller loads, I load the images for that specific task and then call an automatic load of the first image. Alas this is not working...

I have attached a link to show how the method where I believe she is braking -[codepen](http://codepen.io/roblawford/pen/QdedVQ/)...

```
$rootScope.getInitialScreen = function () {
```

I have not included a full example (would be too hectic to code a standalone version) but I have shown how the initial method is called on a loadImages() function, all images load perfectly so that is not where the error is, so I have just put the initialization code up.

**Console.logging the image in the initialization function does show the correct image, it simply is not rendering onto my canvas...** I've tried sizing of image, position of image, image itself and nothing.. Any ideas I would be super grateful!

Thanks.

Comment: image loading is async, simply use load handler on the image element to be sure the image is loaded before attempting to draw it to canvas.

Comment: You don't show the `loadImages` function are you sure it waits for all your images `onload` event ? You can check it by calling `console.log(theImage.naturalWidth)` if it logs `0`, then your image is not loaded yet.

Comment: Thanks for the replies - Yeah i'm sure it's not `loadImages` function, I'm seeing my images in my console when logging and I'm outputting your width log and seeing values for that too.... :(